# Django Single sign on recommendations

Tags: django, single-sign-on

We are looking for a simple Django single sign on package.

Our requirements are quite simple - SSO for a group of Django apps in one project ( site ).

OA-Auth is overkill, I've looked at django-sso and django-simple-sso.

Any recommendations from prior usage for a Django SSO package?

Thanks

Stewart

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at this: [Authentication using REMOTE_USER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/auth-remote-user/) ?

Comment: Link is outdated - here's the most recent: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/auth-remote-user/

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this quite a bit and work at the company, but [django-stormpath](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-django) is pretty awesome for SSO + Django.

You just drop some code into settings.py, and BAM, you have working SSO.